# Using an XML lookup file from within an XSL file in a Java web app

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a few XSL files in my web app for transforming data between different schemas. They are in the src/main/resources folder and work fine with the exception of a few fields for which the value comes from an XML 'lookup' file. These lookup files are included like:

```
<xsl:variable name="genders-top" select="document('lookup-gender.xml')/genders" />
```

This works fine locally (i.e. not in the web app - so the file contents is fine) but fails when compiled into a .war file running on Tomcat. My working assumption is that the path to the XML file needs to be something different, but I can't work out what. I've tried src/main/resources but that didn't work. Any pointers please?

Comment: Posting the failure message you see will greatly improve the question.

Comment: There is no failure message, but any lookup based on the lookup table that is in the external file will fail. In this particular case I simply end up with an empty `<gender />` element where I expect something like `<gender>male</gender>`

Comment: Try specifying full path of the look up file in your document function.